# how to write two strings in a file seperated by space or comma in c?

Tags: c, file, file-io, file-handling

I am having two strings , I want to write these strings to a FILE in the following format:

```
string1 "space/comma" string2 "newline"
string3 "space/comma" string4 "newline"
..
..
..
```

Comment: You say you have two strings, then what are `string3`, `string4`..?

Comment: i am in a loop so after each iteration i'll be doing the same thing with bothe the strings.. plz help thnxxx

Answer (score 5):

```
FILE* fileptr = fopen("file.txt","wt");
fprintf(fileptr,"%s , %s \n",string1,string2);
```

Comment: thanx martin but i want to do that in a FILE (a text file in c), how to do that??  thanxx

Comment: see above, you just open a txt file, and use fprintf instead of printf.